# Inequality with natural numbers

Tags: inequality

I'm stuck with the following inequality: Let $a,b,c,d$ be natural such that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}<1$ Show that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}<1-\frac{1}{(a+c)^3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact,we have follow:

let $a,b,c,d$ be postive integer numbers,and such $$a+c=n,\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}<1$$
then
$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}\le1-\dfrac{1}{\left[\dfrac{2n}{3}+\dfrac{7}{6}\right]\left(\left[\dfrac{2n}{3}+\dfrac{7}{6}\right]\left(n-\left[\dfrac{2n}{3}+\dfrac{1}{6}\right]\right)+1\right)}$$

This is  China Team Selection Test 1993

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=269096&sid=24e7e7db33efdb972dfb489846371f3b#p269096